# xsl reference to external xsl file

Tags: xslt, file, external

I have a question about xsl. I have 1 huge xsl file (+4000 lines :p) and I would like to split the file in different parts. I use the xsl file to map some schemas in BizTalk and it would be more performant if I split it in parts, so I can re-use the parts. Anyway, don't mind the BizTalk stuff, how can I reference from my main xsl file to the different parts?

ex.:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
      <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />
      <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/ns1:ADT_A01_231_GLO_DEF" />
      </xsl:template>
      <xsl:template match="/ns1:ADT_A01_231_GLO_DEF">
        <ns1:ADT_A01_25_GLO_DEF>
          <EVN_EventType>
                <xsl:if test="EVN_EventTypeSegment/EVN_1_EventTypeCode">
                  <EVN_1_EventTypeCode>
                    <xsl:value-of select="EVN_EventTypeSegment/EVN_1_EventTypeCode/text()" />
                  </EVN_1_EventTypeCode>
                </xsl:if>
                <EVN_2_RecordedDateTime>
                  <xsl:if test="EVN_EventTypeSegment/EVN_2_RecordedDateTime/TS_0_TimeOfAnEvent">
                    <TS_0_Time>
                      <xsl:value-of select="EVN_EventTypeSegment/EVN_2_RecordedDateTime/TS_0_TimeOfAnEvent/text()" />
                    </TS_0_Time>
                  </xsl:if>
                  <xsl:if test="EVN_EventTypeSegment/EVN_2_RecordedDateTime/TS_1_DegreeOfPrecision">
                    <TS_1_DegreeOfPrecision>
                      <xsl:value-of select="EVN_EventTypeSegment/EVN_2_RecordedDateTime/TS_1_DegreeOfPrecision/text()" />
                    </TS_1_DegreeOfPrecision>
                  </xsl:if>
                </EVN_2_RecordedDateTime>
          </EVN_EventType>
          <PID_PatientIdentification>
            <xsl:if test="PID_PatientIdentificationSegment/PID_1_SetIdPid">
              <PID_1_SetIdPid>
                <xsl:value-of select="PID_PatientIdentificationSegment/PID_1_SetIdPid/text()" />
              </PID_1_SetIdPid>
            </xsl:if>
           </PID_PatientIdentification>
        </ns1:ADT_A01_25_GLO_DEF>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

So I would like to put the "EVN_EventType" and the "PID_PatientIdentification" in another file.
Could be that this xsl isnt 100% valid, I quickly copy/pasted something, but you get my point?

Greatly appreciate any help.
Thx

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for the xslt instructions that are designed especially with the purpose of using multi-file XSLT transformations,

Comment: Besides the good answers from @LarsH and @Dimitre, you should note that this transformation has a bad design. It is just an identity transformation probably with some stripped or bypassed elements. That could be very much shorter!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`<xsl:import>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#import) at the top level of the stylesheet, to import templates from other stylesheets. You can:

- create a named template for
  EVN_EventType, put it in
  EVN_EventType.xsl
- create another
  named template for
  PID_PatientIdentification, which you
  put in PID_PatientIdentification.xsl;
- then import both stylesheets into your main stylesheet
- and call both    templates from
  within your    `<xsl:template match="/ns1:ADT_A01_231_GLO_DEF">` above.

Answer (score 2):

**Read about the [`<xsl:import>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#import) and [`<xsl:include>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#include) instructions**. Then use the acquired knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You can import an xsl from another xsl by using import statement in the main xsl to use template match from another xsl (say A.xsl). The `<xsl:import>` element has an href attribute whose value is a URI reference identifying the stylesheet to be imported.

```
<xsl:import href="A.xsl"/>
```